# How to write complex sql query, somehow this looks complex

Tags: sql, mysql

Please find the below input table and the relationships:

1. A package is associated to a shipment and a shipment is put into a box.
2. Group of packages also can be associated to a single shipment and each package can be put into different boxes.

Now if we look at the input table below at a shipment level

S1 is placed in B1 and B2.
S2 is placed in B2 and B3.
S3 is placed in B3 and B4.
And this can go on and at the same pattern, however it will get cut at a point.
S4 is placed into B4.

Now the above data I wanted to make to a group, so that I can move all the boxes together. There could be a case where single package can go into single shipment and single box example in the case below of P10

| Package Number | Shipment Number | Box Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | S1 | B1 |
| P2 | S1 | B2 |
| P3 | S2 | B2 |
| P4 | S2 | B3 |
| P5 | S3 | B3 |
| P6 | S3 | B4 |
| P7 | S4 | B4 |
| P8 | S5 | B5 |
| P9 | S5 | B6 |
| P10 | S6 | B7 |

I would like to get two outputs
Output 1 : which has additional columns Group Number and Group Name

| Package Number | Shipment Number | Box Number | Group Number | Group Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | S1 | B1 | 1 | G1 |
| P2 | S1 | B2 | 1 | G1 |
| P3 | S2 | B2 | 1 | G1 |
| P4 | S2 | B3 | 1 | G1 |
| P5 | S3 | B3 | 1 | G1 |
| P6 | S3 | B4 | 1 | G1 |
| P7 | S4 | B4 | 1 | G1 |
| P8 | S5 | B5 | 2 | G2 |
| P9 | S5 | B6 | 2 | G2 |
| P10 | S6 | B7 | 3 | G3 |

Output 2 : which is grouped at a Box level and having Box linkage data

| Box Number | Group Number | Group Name | Box Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | 1 | G1 | B2,B3,B4 |
| B2 | 1 | G1 | B1,B3,B4 |
| B3 | 1 | G1 | B1,B2,B4 |
| B4 | 1 | G1 | B1,B2,B3 |
| B5 | 2 | G2 | B6 |
| B6 | 2 | G2 | B5 |
| B7 | 3 | G3 |  |

I tried making self joins, product joins by creating two different tables at shipment level,box level somehow couldn't make it .

Comment: There is no logic that I can see for allocation of group numbers..

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon, thankyou for your response. Please find the below logic.  S1 = B1 + B2, S2 = B2 + B3, S3 = B3 + B4, S4 = B4. Now this forms group 1. Similarly S5 is present in B5 and B6 so it forms group 2. S6 is present in only B7 hence it forms Group 3.

Comment: There is no applicable logic then...

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 1 r, p.*, 1 g from packages p where p.package_id = 'P1'
    union all
    select c.r + 1, p.*, case when c.shipment_num = p.shipment_num or 
                                c.box_num = p.box_num then c.g else c.g + 1 end g 
    from cte c 
    join packages p on cast(regexp_substr(p.package_id, '\\d+') as unsigned) = c.r + 1
),
groupings as (
    select c.package_id, c.shipment_num, c.box_num, c.g group_num, concat('G', c.g) group_name 
    from cte c
)
-- Output 1
select * from groupings
```

Generating Output 2, using a self-`join`:

```
select g.box_num, group_concat(distinct case when g2.box_num is null then '' else g2.box_num end) 
from groupings g 
left join groupings g2 on g2.group_num = g.group_num and g.box_num != g2.box_num 
group by g.box_num
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ewuxtq97)

Comment: Thankyou @Ajax1234. Is there a way of not hardcoding where p.package_id = 'P1'

Comment: @Tinku The condition can be changed to reflect whatever is the first package ID in the chain